# Traducir contenido de una lista (solo permite traducir str)

Tags: python

Estoy usando el codigo de AWS traductor.

```
import boto3

palabras = ["Incluye toda la informacion", "quien necesitaría", "hola, como estas", "me alegra saberlo"]

translate = boto3.client('translate')
result = translate.translate_text(Text=palabras,
                                  SourceLanguageCode="es",
                                  TargetLanguageCode="pt")
print(f'TranslatedText: {result["TranslatedText"]}')
print(f'SourceLanguageCode: {result["SourceLanguageCode"]}')
print(f'TargetLanguageCode: {result["TargetLanguageCode"]}')
```

Fuente: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-translate-TranslateText.py.html

Todo funciona bien cuando es un *str* lo que trato de traducir, pero tengo una serie de *str* dentro de una lista. Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo le hago para que se traduzcan todos los elementos dentro de la lista `palabras` y salga una lista con el mismo orden, pero traducido?

Hay que recordar que el resultado lo muestra
`print(f'TranslatedText: {result["TranslatedText"]}')`
pero como dije, solo cuando es un *str*. Cuando intento hacerlo con el código de arriba me sale el error:
`type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>`

Comment: ¿no puedes hacer un bucle que itere por la lista, traduzca cada frase, y recopile los resultados en otra lista? Algo como `result= [translate...(Text=frase,...) for frase in palabras]`

Comment: Pense en un bucle que traduzca y luego haga un append en una lista vacia, pero, sinceramente no se cual via tomar para lograrlo (gajes de ser nuevo con este lenguaje).

Comment: nota: el problema no esta en result, el problema esta en "Text=palabras"

Comment: Ya, por eso no le paso la lista palabras, sino un solo elemento de la lista (al que llamé frase), dentro de un bucle

Comment: Ya lo hice de esa forma, pero, el problema ahora esta en que genera varios **result["TranslatedText"]** es decir, no los pone en una sola lista, con que genera "varios" me refiero a que dentro de **result** aparecen varios, cuando imprimo **result["TranslatedText"]**  obviamente sale un error de **TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

Answer (score 0):

Sin tener acceso al servicio para probar el código, creo que podrías hacer algo así:

```
# función que traduce un string y devuelve el objeto resultado desde el servicio,
# en este caso un dict:

def traducir(texto):
    resultado = translate.translate_text(Text=texto, 
                                         SourceLanguageCode="es", 
                                         TargetLanguageCode="pt")
    return resultado
```

```
# genera lista de dicts con las respuestas
respuestas = []
# itera sobre la lista 'palabras'

for palabra in palabras:
    respuesta = traducir(palabra)
    respuestas.append(respuesta)
```

Finalmente puedes generar la lista con las frases traducidas, iterando sobre la lista de objetos, y extrayendo los valores "TranslatedText" de cada dict:

```
[respuesta['TranslatedText'] for respuesta in respuestas]
```

O:

```
[traducir(palabra)['TranslatedText'] for palabra in palabras]
```

Espero te sirva! Y ojalá puedas comentar si funciona con acceso al servicio.